# Label Angle using tikz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am trying to recreate this diagram. I can get most of it except for the labelling of the top angle.
 [image]

An MWE is below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (A) at (4,0); 
\coordinate (B) at (0,2); 
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\node (a) at (1.4,2.1) {$90^{\circ}-\theta$}; 
\node (b) at (0.1,1.8){}; 
\path (a) edge [->,bend left=45,looseness=0.8] (b); 

\tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){$b$}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=2pt](O,B){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above right=2pt](A,B){$c$}
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.3](A,O,B)

\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1.0](O,A,B){$\theta$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your problem with placing an arrow from the angle measurement to the angle as shown in your illustration?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Since you have solved this problem, it is recommended to answer your own question. You don't have to answer your own question, which will leave the question open and upset the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is based on using `angle` of nodes. 295 and 300 are my choices.

```
\path (a.295) edge [->,bend left=45,looseness=1] (b.300);
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't know of the angle specification inside a node. Problem solved.